# Java: Getting where an application runs on Linux

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

I wrote the following code to find where my application is running.

While it works fine on Windows it seems that on Linux it trims to many characters.

As reported by one of my users, this code is returning the path `Users/mini/Downloads/preferences.properties` instead of `/Users/mini/Downloads/preferences.properties`,

While on windows it returns correctly `D:\work\Zploger\zploger\target\classes\preferences.properties`

This is the code:

```
public static Path getApplicationPath(Class<?> clazz, String... subpath) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Path file = null;
    try {
        String resName = "/" + clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        final URL url = clazz.getResource(resName);
        final String protocol = url.getProtocol();
        String path = URLDecoder.decode(url.toString(), "UTF-8");
        // returns "file:/D:/work/Zploger/zploger/target/classes/com/zparkingb/zploger/Compute/MyApp.class"

        // Case 1): in a jar.
        if (protocol.equals("jar")) {
            // suppression of "jar:file:" from the url
            // (...)
            }
        }

        // Case 2): in a file
        if (protocol.equals("file")) {
            // suppression of "file:" from the url
            int index = path.lastIndexOf(resName);
            if (index >= 5) {
                path = path.substring(6, index);
                // returns "D:/work/Zploger/zploger/target/classes"

                file = Paths.get(path);
            }
        }

        if (file == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find application path. Invalid path:  " + path);
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find application path", e);
    }

    for (String string : subpath) {
        if (subpath != null) {
            file = file.resolve(string);
        }
    }

    return file;

}
```

Is there a more generic algorithm that would work for both Windows, Linux, MacOs ?

Is there a way to have a different algorithm for Windows, Linux, ... ?

And what is complicated my task is that I don't have a Linux system around to test my app :-(

Comment: Use a virtual machine like VirtualBox and Debian as Linux. Both are free to use.

Comment: I'm new to Virtual Machine and Linux. Which Linux distribution would you recommend ?

Comment: Many people suggest Ubuntu as an easy Linux distribution. This is true. Nevertheless I recommend Debian as your first Linux distribution. It may be a bit harder to learn, but you definitely learn more about Linux. I also strongly support the idea of Debian to be 100% open source. Debian has 3 main distributions _**stable - testing - unstable**_. I recommend _**stable**_. For high end hardware I recommend _**testing**_. By the way, Ubuntu is a derivate of Debian, and Ubuntu uses the _**unstable**_ distribution of Debian. Many tutorials which work for Debian also work for Ubuntu and vice versa.

Comment: Linux has many different desktop environments. For example, modern Windows has only 1 desktop environment, called Explorer. Linux has 2 big desktop environments, first is called GNOME (more like Apple Mac-OS), this is the default for Ubuntu, second is KDE (more like MS Windows). On every Linux you are able to change the default desktop environment, so you could also install Ubuntu with KDE (this is called Kubuntu). Debian has no default desktop environment. Minor desktop environments are Cinnamon (Windows 7 like), XFCE (GNOME like, good on old PC), MATE (old version of GNOME, good on old PC).

Comment: I took the wrong one :-D I went for Debian and I couldn't manage to see any desktop. I understand now. I heading now to Kubuntu. Thanks.